# Using Ticker in Bloomberg of Instead of Cusip to Download Industry Sector

Tags: api, bloomberg, ticker, sector

I know I can use this sample Bloomberg API code `(=BDP("459200101 CUSIP","INDUSTRY_SECTOR"))` to download the industry sector (Muni, Corp, Equity, Pfd, etc.).

How can I download the industry sectors using tickers (w/o industry sector in the code) instead of cusips?

Answer (score 1):

Using the ticker + exchange + yellow key. For example:

```
=BDP("IBM US Equity","INDUSTRY_SECTOR")
```